# Stop a function from another function - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have a function that is called by a dropdown change. It is possible that the function is running and the user changes the dropdown.

If that happens I want the function that is running to stop.

Ex.

```
$('.txtCategory').change(function(){
    ajaxPost('para', 'meters').stop(); //doesn't work
    $('#Submit').attr('data-check', 'on');
    $('#Submit').val('Stop Checking');
});
```

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Greets,
Guido

Comment: Show where the other function is called

Comment: If you have a callback, as in an ajax success, you could set a flag and check the flag value to see if you can process the data or if the value has changed. But this is as far as you can go in "stopping" a function.

Comment: Well, you can't but just out of curiosity: you do realize that `ajaxPost().stop()` effectively calls `ajaxPost`, and applies the `stop` method to the _return value of that function_, right? So logically, you can't stop `ajaxPost` this way, because the `stop` method will only be called _after_ `ajaxPost` has returned

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem That is logical and that's why I commented 'doesn't work' behind it.

Comment: @GuidoVisser: just wanted to make sure that you knew that that was a fundamental flaw in what you wrote. Didn't mean to come across like a pedantic git (though I can be at times )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible for a simple reason : your script execution happens on only one thread, only one function can run at a time.

Any callback responding to a local event or to a query won't be called until the current function has finished execution.

Answer (score 0):

@Guido

I think you want some other things.. Please explain your question in better... I think this isn't what you really want achieve..

Also you can use these

```
Create a setTimeOut function call and run it every 1000ms so whenever you want to
stop that setTimeOut function you can simple use clearTimeOut to stop it.
it will help you out. if you have still any issues let me know :)
```

Comment: Yep, I thought about a setTimeOut inside the "dropdown change" function that checks for changes and if it changes it quits out of the function. It's not a good idea, but it's doable.

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned It is not possible to stop/abort a function from another as they both are sync process. On the other hand if you want to stop/abort a AJAX (first A stands for *Asynchronous*) request you can do that with the help of jQuery's AJAX return object. To do that you can follow the following steps;

First create a global variable to handle AJAX object;

```
var xhr = null;
```

When you request by AJAX assign the return object to this variable;

```
xhr = $.ajax(
    url: "http://someurl.org",
    success: function() { ... }
    );
```

Now when you need to abort request just a `xhr.abort()` call should do the trick.

```
if (xhr != null)
    xhr.abort();
```

Hope that helps;

Answer (score 0):

As others stated it is impossible to stop a function out of another function in JavaScript.

However, you may use flags to check whether the Ajax request is now running. For that purposes jQuery has non documented `$.active`property. You may use it as follows:

```
$(".txtCategory").change(function() {
    if ($.active > 0)    // if there are more than 0 Ajax requests running
        return false;    // at a time we stop executing the current callback

    ajaxPost("para", "meters");
    $("#Submit").data("check", "on").val("Stop Checking");
});
```